# Adding a vector to matrix rows in numpy

Tags: vector, matrix, numpy

Is there a fast way in numpy to add a vector to every row or column of a matrix.

Lately, I have been tiling the vector to the size of the matrix, which can use a lot of memory. For example

```
    mat=np.arange(15)
    mat.shape=(5,3)

    vec=np.ones(3)
    mat+=np.tile(vec, (5,1))
```

The other way I can think of is using a python loop, but loops are slow:

```
    for i in xrange(len(mat)):
        mat[i,:]+=vec
```

Is there a fast way to do this in numpy without resorting to C extensions?

It would be nice to be able to virtually tile a vector, like a more flexible version of broadcasting. Or to be able to iterate an operation row-wise or column-wise, which you may almost be able to do with some of the ufunc methods.

Comment: Could you give another example?  The one you've given would give the same answer just with `mat + vec`, so I'm not sure exactly what you're after.  [Incidentally, this is an `array`, not a `matrix`.]

Comment: by matrix, I mean a 2-d array (a matrix in the mathematical sense)

Comment: I want to add the same 1-d array to every row of the 2d array

Comment: In numpy, a `matrix` is different from a 2d `array`.  For example, multiplication is matrix multiplication on `matrix` objects but elementwise on `array` objects, so it's a good idea to keep them distinct.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

For adding a 1d array to every row, broadcasting already takes care of things for you:

```
mat += vec
```

However more generally you can use `np.newaxis` to coerce the array into a broadcastable form. For example:

```
mat + np.ones(3)[np.newaxis,:]
```

While not necessary for adding the array to every row, this is necessary to do the same for column-wise addition:

```
mat + np.ones(5)[:,np.newaxis]
```

**EDIT:** as Sebastian mentions, for row addition, `mat + vec` already handles the broadcasting correctly. It is also faster than using `np.newaxis`. I've edited my original answer to make this clear.

Comment: Here its not even necessary, but if mat would be shaped (3,5) then using np.ones(3)[:,np.newaxis] does the trick.

Comment: @Sebastian: You are right; I was just trying to show a general method of getting the broadcasting correct since the OP asked for both columns and row addition.

Comment: Okay, I must be really stupid today.  Could someone explain to me why this isn't just a slower version of `mat + vec`?

Comment: @DSM not being stupid. See my edit above. I should have been clear that what I was demonstrating was a general method for coercing arrays into a broadcasting friendly shape.

Comment: It looks like mat + vec works when vec is the same size as the number of columns in mat, but you need newaxis to add columns.

Comment: In numpy 1.18 I am getting the error `numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'add' output from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') with casting rule 'same_kind'` when trying to run the `mat += vec` line. The `np.newaxis` technique works though.

Comment: @Trevor The error is telling you that you are trying to add two numpy arrays with different datatypes, which is causing the error. Making both `mat` and `vec` with the same dtype.

Comment: Update as of 2020: numpy handles the broadcasting correctly with adding a column to a matrix without the explicit broadcasting syntax, if the number of rows is the same. E.g.: `np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]) + np.array([[1],[2],[3]])` gives `array([[2, 3], [5, 6], [8, 9]])`

Answer (score 0):

Numpy broadcasting will automatically add a compatible size vector (1D array) to a matrix (2D array, not numpy `matrix`). It does this by matching shapes based on dimension from right to left, "stretching" missing or value 1 dimensions to match the other. This is explained in https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html:

```
mat:               5 x 3
vec:                   3
vec (broadcasted): 5 x 3
```

By default, numpy [arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) are row-major ("C order"), with axis 0 is "matrix row" and axis 1 is "matrix col", so the broadcasting clones the vector as matrix rows along axis 0.